# Spring Security with Active Directory shows *Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations*

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I use AD (non-cloud) Active Directory to authenticate user which works as expected. I have class like below:

Note that I have enabled security debugging with `@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)` in order to view security debugging information

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)  // ENABLE SECURITY DEBUGGING HERE
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ad.userDnPattern}")
    private String adUserDnPattern;

    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String adUrl;

    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String adDomain;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .anonymous().disable()  // DISABLE ANONYMOUS
                .formLogin().disable();
   }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider() {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ad = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(adLdapDomain, adLdapUrl, adLdapUserDnPattern);
        ad.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        ad.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        String adSearchFilter = "(&(sAMAccountName={1})(objectClass=user))";
        // String adSearchFilter = "(&(userPrincipalName={0})(objectClass=user))"; // SAME OUTCOME
        ad.setSearchFilter(adSearchFilter);

        return ad;
    }

   ...
}
```

Above, I set my searchFilter to use this AD filter using **AMAccountName** like `(&(sAMAccountName={1})(objectClass=user))` (Same result happens if I use instead `(&(userPrincipalName={0})(objectClass=user))` instead).

My authentication/authorization mechanism works as expected and I am very happy about it. However, with enabled security debugging (above `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` ), I am seeing an INFO level message in the console when I run my application like this:

**Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations**

This tells me clearly that the application will allow users to access it anonymously without having to authenticate. Someone recommended to add line to HttpSecurity configuration above which I did (see line `.anonymous().disable()`) but this makes no difference.

I have spent days trying to figure out how to prevent this but I could not find any help on how to do this when connecting to AD.

My understanding is that using `&(sAMAccountName={1})` and / or `&(userPrincipalName={0})` will plug in the registered AD userId of the user trying to authenticate, into the place holders {1} and / or {0} above. If user is present in AD, authentication will be successful. Otherwise, it will fail. I have exactly this behavior, so all good.

**PROBLEM:**
I do not understand why the INFO message says that anonymous context will be used for read-write operations. I do not want to use anonymous mode so I do not want that INFO message to appear since it is raising questions as we do not want to allow anonymous (meaning unknown users) to log in.

I understand it is not an error message and my solution is behaving as expected but it is clearly having a smell.